# Get specific results from this table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table like this: (translations_tb)

```
NID LANGUAGE (translations_tb)
 1     fr
 1     en
 2     fr
 2     en
 3     fr
 3     en
 4     en
 5     en
```

I need a query that will get the results like this:

1. All the NID's with FR language
2. All the NID's with EN language that are != FR NID's
3. SORT BY : FR language first and EN last ( Could be DE, RU, RO, etc. languages)

This is how it should work for the example above.

```
NID   LANGUAGE
1       fr
2       fr
3       fr
4       en
5       en
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT nid, CASE WHEN language = 'fr' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as new_language 
FROM translations_tb
WHERE language in ('fr', 'en')
ORDER BY new_language ASC
```

This gets it sorted by my dynamic language first, but I know I should not use IN ('fr', 'en') but can't figure out what should I do in order to exclude the duplicate NID's that are from EN language.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic language"?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: It couldn't be de, ru, ro. It's only ever fr or en

Comment: By dynamic language I mean that whatever the language is (de, jp, ua) the query will get it sorted by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have condition with language =  'fr' and then add a condition for 'en' using a subquery to exclude those  with language 'fr'

```
select nid, language
from translations_tb
where language = 'fr'
   or (language = 'en' and nid not in (select nid 
                                       from translations_tb 
                                       where language = 'fr'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `GROUP BY nid` and fetch `max(language)`, which will return `'fr'`, if both languages are present for that `nid`, because `'fr' > 'en'`. For the same reason you can order by the language descending to have `'fr'` first in the result.

```
SELECT nid,
       max(language) language
       FROM translations_tb
       WHERE language IN ('fr',
                          'en')
       GROUP BY nid
       ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: This query won't work if the language of interest is `'de'`

Comment: @Nick: Indeed. You had to change `max()` to `min()` and `DESC` to `ASC` or nothing (and `'fr'` to `'de'`).